# Text in textbox is selected - how to change?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, textbox, focus

I created a simple form in C# with only a textbox and a button.
The form contains a function to set the text in the textbox and another function that closes the form if the button is clicked.
Now I execute the form, set the text and display the form.
Everything is fine, but: The text in the textbox is "selected / marked".

What can I do that the text is not selected and the focus is on the button?
(`button.focus` is not working)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You can manually set the selection after changing the content, for example like this:

```
this.textBox1.SelectionStart = this.textBox1.Text.Length;
```

Where textBox1 is the textbox you're working with. This clears the previous selection and makes a new one, effectively setting the cursor inside the textbox to the last element of it's content.

Alternatively, select the button instead of focussing it, like this:

```
this.button1.Select();
```

Where button1 is the button you want to select after changing the textbox' content.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
I changed the TabIndex from textbox from 0 to 1 and
have tabindex 0 to the button.
Then text is no longer marked.

Comment: your question was far from this solution so i edited it, glad you got it resolved.